# Retrieving drawable from overlayitem

Tags: android, android-maps

Is there any clever way of retrieving the `Drawable` from an `OverlayItem`?

I want to store the `Drawable` of an `OverlayItem` before setting a new `Drawable` on it, to be able to revert afterwards, but I can't find any way of actually retrieving the current `Drawable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are the one defining the `Drawable` in the first place. Make note of what it is at the time you set it up or change it. Most likely, you will need to create your own subclass of `OverlayItem` for this.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there would be an easier way, but I guess I can live with that.